# Why is Flyway hanging forever when executing a migration?

Tags: docker, macos, ubuntu, flyway

I'm having this problem on three different MacBook's so I'm hoping someone can help. My application is dockerized and based from an Ubuntu 18.04 image. During deployment, I create an Ubuntu container, and execute a script that pulls credentials, executes 'flyway migrate', and then some other deployment commands.

On Windows, this script works fine and I've never had an issue. On three separate Macbooks though, 4/5 times the command 'flyway migrate' hangs forever, immediately after issuing the command. Even if I add `-X` at the end for debug logging, nothing is ever output. It simply hangs forever and has to be terminated.

It DOES work occasionally, and sometimes consecutively. If you issue command `flyway migrate` repeatedly from inside of the same container, it will succeed a few times, and then hang the very next time. Or maybe it will hang everytime.

When I use the flyway docker image from dockerhub, it works every time, so it seems to be limited to Using flyway inside of an Ubuntu docker image, on a mac.

Anyone have any suggestions?

I have tried removing my scripting from the equation and starting a base Ubuntu docker image and installing flyway on it. The same behavior occurs, and "some/most" flyway migrate commands hang forever.

Comment: [Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: ("Code" is "relative". Show an exemplary script invoking *flyway*.)